# Math class can be puzzling

Tags: riddle, wordplay

In math class, someone was writing down a poem:

***Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling***

***In mystic force and magic spelling***

***Celestial sprites elucidate***

***All my own striving can't relate***

Then, of course...

***What am I?***

Later that day, the kid asked if anyone knew. No one did.

The kid didn't know either, and we were stuck thinking about it.

That night, I had a moment of "wow!". I told everyone, and they said it was genius.

So, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's another

> mnemonic for the decimal expansion of pi: word lengths yield digits.

Some others:

> "How I need a drink, alcoholic of course, after the heavy lectures involving quantum mechanics". "Now I, even I, would celebrate / In rhymes unapt the great / Immortal Syracusan rivaled nevermore / Who in his wondrous lore / Passed on before / Gave men his guidance / How to circles mensurate". (That one doesn't work in British English where "rivalled" has one more letter.) "'I wish I could remember pi ... Eureka!' cried the great inventor. 'Christmas pudding, Christmas pie, is the problem's very centre."

There's always a bit of an issue

> about the digit *zero*. Fortunately, it's a while before there are any. 3.14159265358979323846246338327950...